# How to display custom Trace information?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, trace

I need to display custom Trace messages at a specific line of code in my WPF application.

I would like those messages during debugging only (like in the output window or so).

Basically I need something similar to the result of console.log() browser alike.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788

Comment: [`Debug.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline)

Comment: @MartinLiversage please post it as answer I would be glad to accept it. Thanks!

Comment: Useful: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815788

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Debug.WriteLine](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline) in the `System.Diagnostics` namespace to write output during debug. By default the output will appear in the **Output** window of Visual Studio while debugging. Also, in release mode no calls will be made because the methods are annotated by a `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` attribute which will instruct the compiler to generate no code at all for the call.

Alternatively, you can use [`Trace.WriteLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.diagnostics.trace.writeline) and these calls will be retained in a release build provided that the `TRACE` preprocessor symbols is defined in the properties for the project.

Answer (score 0):

`Debug.WriteLine` or `Trace.WriteLine`